# Workflow to create Firebase users from Cloud Function

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am creating an Angular app with a Google Firebase backend.  I have a many to many relationship between "users" and "clubs" as follows:

| User | Club |
| --- | --- |
| First Name | Name |
| Last Name | Member Count |
| Phone no | Collection of Documents with User Name, User Role and User's Membership Reference |
| Clubs[] -array of maps with Club Name, Club ID, User's Role and User's Membership Reference |  |
| Messages subcollection |  |

*The User Document uses an array because the number of clubs will be small (3-4 at most, usually 1), and always needs retrieving.  The Club Document uses a subcollection because the number of members will be large and doesn't always need to be retreived.*

Users are created by the Club administrator.  They will not know if a given email address already exists (because they already had an account with another club), or if they are brand new to the app.

I have a Cloud function with the following workflow, passing the new user email to begin:

1. Check the request has correct privelage to add a user
2. See if a user exists with the given email
3. If no user exists, create a user with that email
4. Then in either case, add custom claims to the auth user, add an entry to the Club array in the User and create a doc in the Club/members collection with the required information
5. Add a document to the messages subcollection so the user can see they were added next time they sign in (relevant if they already had an account).

The problem is that if a new user is created at step 3, they are always created with no password, and also no name/phone number etc, as these aren't known to the club administrator.  Without a password no way to sign in!  What is the best way to solve this?  I was trying to get the backend to send a single sign on link which would force the user to add a password and the required information if they are new, but this seems difficult.  Alternatively I was thinking about making the user visit the app then doing a password reset, but again this doesn't feel very user friendly.  The experience has got to be really easy, and for the moment I only plan to use Email/Password or optionally Passwordless sign in.

Would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Firebase Auth Method called `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` which creates a new user account associated with the specified email address and password. On successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application. User account creation can fail if the account already exists or the password is invalid.

You may refer on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) for more information.

In addition, you may also check the [Firebase User API Properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#properties) if you want to update user details after the user creation which can make the user experience easier.

---

**EDIT: 2021-12-10**

Considering the use case description, there are 2 technique(s) that might be worth exploring (other than Email & Password technique already recommended earlier). The authentication method selection should be done after evaluating all the dimensions & fitment of the use case.

- [**Anonymous Authentication**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) - This method enables temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase and explore your website or application. If the anonymous user decides to sign up to your app (later), you can link their sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue to work with their protected data in future sessions.

  *There's also a case study of a real user that used Anonymous Authentication to their advantage. You may also want to check this out [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/case-studies/fabulous.pdf).*
- [**Email Link Authentication**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) - This technique allows signing in a user by sending them an email containing a link, which they can click to sign in (without a password). In the process, the user's email address is also verified. Later on, this method of authentication may be linked to other techniques like phone number authentication for a pre-existing user or email/password method.

The above 2 techniques would allow you to not worry about generating the password and your related security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply.  I am aware that I could create a user with a defined password, but there are a couple of problems with this - especially as the account is created by someone else.
+ How would I securely generate a random password?
+ How could I advise the created user what the password is?  It's not best practice to send plaintext in an email.
Currently I just do this (Cloud Function)
`newUser = await admin.auth().createUser({ email });`
Which creates a user and allows me to do other backend work now I have their UID, but they can't log in!

Comment: Hi @GuyJoseph, I've updated my answer.